# Kafka rebalance clarification

Tags: apache-kafka, spring-kafka

I'm using spring-kafka 1.3.5 which uses 0.11.0.2 client.
I have 2 partitions. And my max.poll.records = 1.

My question is: Suppose I have 2 nodes/workers(which have concurrency set to one , so one consumer in each node) which are slow workers(might take 5 mins to process records), both are currently shutdown. When node-1(consumer-1) joins a consumer group , it gets 2 partitions(p-1,p-2) assigned to it. Now consumer-1 consumes message from p-1. And immediately node-2(consumer-2) joins the same consumer group.

1. Is there a chance that p-1 gets assigned to consumer-2 or kafka
   knows that consumer-1 is currently processing message so it assigns
   partition-2 to consumer-2? If this can happen, can node-2 pull the same
   message(since it is not ack'ed yet) from p-1 and when consumer-1
   finishes processing and when tries to commit its offset, will there be a
   CommmitFailedException or any exception thrown?
2. Can a consumer call syncCommits() on a partition that it no more owns?
       And will there be an exception thrown?

Comment: Are you sure of this? I know for sure that CommitFailed exception is thrown when cosumer goes dead(because it did not call poll in max.poll.interval.ms and rebalance happened) and when it tried to call syncCommit

Comment: https://kafka.apache.org/0100/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/CommitFailedException.html

Answer (score 1):

The responsibility of assigning partitions to a consumer in a consumerGroup is the responsibility of the Consumer Group Leader which is one of the consumers not the Kafka Broker which is co-ordinator for that consumer group. The Kafka Broker which is the group-co-ordinator will only trigger a rebalance i.e. notify the Consumer group leader that a new consumer has joined the group and there needs to be re-assignment of partitions.

Kafka does not store any state such as which messages are currently being processed, only thing which it stores is the offsets for each partition in a topic committed by a consumerGroup.

To assign partitions, Kafka has three partition assignment strategies- Range and RoundRobin and Sticky Assignor. You can read more about it here.

Range Assignor - https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/index.html?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RangeAssignor.html

Round-Robin Assignor - https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/RoundRobinAssignor.html

Sticky Assignor - https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/StickyAssignor.html

As for your two questions above,it is totally possible for consumer 2 to get assigned partition 1 and hence receiving a message which is already processed. And if ur doing a manual offset commit, yes you should receive a CommitFailed Exception, when consumer 1 tries to commit its offset, regardless if it owns P1 or not.

Comment: Regardsless if it owns or not? Well if consumer-2 gets p-2 then this CommitFailed exception does not happen right?

Comment: i am not 100% sure how Kafka Algorithms are, but I will be really surprised, if they allow committing of offset after a rebalance has happened, unless they have a state maintained in the consumer, the last retrieved consumer record belongs to which partition, which is just messy.

Comment: The reason why I feel that is because kafka consumer stores metadata, such as which partition it has been assigned and who is the Leader for that partition. After a rebalance, that data will be just refreshed. It will be really messy to try to remember which partitions it owned before etc.

Comment: Makes sense though. But commitSync(final Map<TopicPartition, OffsetAndMetadata> offsets) knows which is the Partition and Offset that it has to commit.

Comment: But, what if u call commitSync() only, I doubt even if u specify a map of partitions and metadata, it will allow u to do a commit after a rebalance happens for the previous poll. Shouldn't be differential like that.